I need to make a backup of a sqlite database using NET 8 MAUI for android 13 on tablets
I have a program made with NET 8 MAUI in Visual Studio 2022.
When I pass The path to validate if it exists, is telling me that it does not exist and the file is in that path, the tablet where I install the program to make the backup has Android 13.
The code is the following:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //CopyAndCompressSQLiteFile();
        InitializeAsync();
    }

    private void CopyAndCompressSQLiteFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var sourcePath = @"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.esri.survey123/files/ArcGIS/My Surveys/Databases/a084e65cd9403d813e8ec667ca329a63.sqlite";
            //var sourcePath = @"Este equipo\Galaxy Tab A9\Almacenamiento interno\Android\data\com.esri.survey123\files\ArcGIS\My Surveys\Databases\a084e65cd9403d813e8ec667ca329a63.sqlite";

            var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "backup.sqlite");

            //CopyDatabaseContent(sourcePath, targetFilePath);

            // Verifica si el archivo existe en la ubicación de origen
            if (File.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El archivo existe en la ubicación de origen.");

                // Copia el archivo
                File.Copy(sourcePath, targetFilePath, overwrite: true);

                // Comprime el archivo
                using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(targetFilePath + ".zip", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                    {
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(targetFilePath, Path.GetFileName(targetFilePath));
                    }
                }

                Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Operación exitosa", "Archivo copiado y comprimido exitosamente", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("El archivo no existe en la ubicación de origen.");
                Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "El archivo no existe en la ubicación de origen.", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", $"Error de acceso no autorizado: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", $"Archivo no copiado: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
    }


    private async void InitializeAsync()
    {
        bool hasPermissions = await RequestPermissionsAsync();
        if (hasPermissions)
        {
            CopyAndCompressSQLiteFile();
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("No se concedieron los permisos necesarios.");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Verificar permisos de acceso", "No se concedieron los permisos necesarios.", "OK");
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> RequestPermissionsAsync()
    {
        var storageReadStatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        if (storageReadStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.StorageRead>())
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Asignar Permiso lectura", "Se requieren permisos de lectura y escritura para continuar.", "OK");
            }

            // Solicitar el permiso
            storageReadStatus = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        }

        var storageWriteStatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        if (storageWriteStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            // Solicitar el permiso
            storageWriteStatus = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        }

        if (storageReadStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageWriteStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            // Notificar al usuario que los permisos son necesarios
            await DisplayAlert("Permisos requeridos", "Se requieren permisos de lectura y escritura para continuar.", "OK");
        }

        return storageReadStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted && storageWriteStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted;
    }


I need to copy the survey sqlite database file located in the path I am giving

Why are you using a hardocded path instead of building it using Environment.SpecialFolders?

How do I reach the name that is in that path without using hardcoding?

you are not hardcoding targetFilePath

My question is because I do not have access to reading the sqlite file in the path that I put in hard on a tablet with Android 13

How do you not have access?  What path are you using to create your db connection?

What I need is to copy the file that is in that path and send it to the Documents folder of the tablet with Android 13 or 14, but it says that it is not in that path, and the file is there: var sourcePath = @"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.esri.survey123/files/ArcGIS/My Surveys/Databases/a084e65cd9403d813e8ec667ca329a63.sqlite";
if (File.Exists(sourcePath))

The sourcePath is android internal storage. Do you want your app to access another app's internal storage?

Here is the official doc for File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android. You may refer to it.
